# How could i loop through every OTHER element in a table in Roblox.lua

Tags: lua, roblox

I am trying to loop through every other element in an table but I cannot find a way to do so.

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: use the `step` parameter of the [numerical for-loop](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#3.3.5). if you want to start at the second element use an initial value of 2. if you're wondering how to achieve something with a loop the first step would be to refer to the Lua manual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends what kind of table you're working with. If you have an array-like table, you can use a simple for-loop :

```
local t = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}

-- start at 1, loop until i > the length of t, increment i by 2 every loop
for i = 1, #t, 2 do
    local val = t[i]
    print(val) -- will print out : 1, 3, 5, 7
end
```

But if you have a dictionary-like table, you will need something to track which key to skip. You could use a simple boolean to keep track, but be aware that there is no guaranteed order of a dictionary-like table.

```
local t = {
    a = 1,
    b = 2,
    c = 3,
    d = 4,
}

local shouldPrint = true
for k, v in pairs(t) do
    -- only print the value when it's true
    if shouldPrint then
        print(k, v) -- will probably print    a, 1   and   c, 3
    end

    -- swap shouldPrint's value every loop
    shouldPrint = !shouldPrint
end
```

Answer (score -2):

Maybe try this

```
local count = 0
for i = 1 , #table/2 do 
table[count + i].value = value
count = count + 1
end
```

Add to the count as you go down

Comment: Include math.floor or ceil of #table/2 for more precision

Comment: table holds Lua's table library. you shouldn't use it as a variable name. also without providing more code this code does not make any sense. what is table[count+i].value? what is value?  why not simply use stepsize 2 instead of that weird count construct?

Comment: This was done from a phone. I assumed one could gather the fact that "table" should be replaced with the tables actual name.... And yes you could use the stepsize but this is another way. I dont understand why youre critisizing my answer when it gives the same result lol im a beginner so i give the most basic results so fellow beginners can understand